# Display search result from multiple dropdown selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I want to display search result from multiple dropdown selection. I have 4 dropdowns. I have one submit button, but I'm still confused how to display search result when I click that submit button. I want to display **"institution" and "address" column from "courseplace" table**, based on query in **mymodel.php** below, and display 'No Results' when no match. I want to display search result like on http://www.bhinneka.com/category/notebook___laptop_gaming.aspx (institution image, institution name, and address).

Do I need new page to display search result?

I have tried so many ways but still failed :(

Thank you very much for the answer!

Below is my code (using Codeigniter) :

**Controller.php**

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

**mymodel.php**

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model 
{
public function getinstitution() 
    {
    include('application/views/home.php');
    $institution = $_POST['DropdownInstitution'];
    $course = $_POST['DropdownCourse'];
    $location = $_POST['DropdownLocation'];
    $price = $_POST['DropdownPrice'];

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('courseplace');
    $this->db->where('1 = 1');
    if ($institution != '') {
        $this->db->where('institution', $institution);
    }
    if ($course != '') {
        $this->db->where('course', $course);
    }
    if ($location != '') {
        $this->db->where('location', $location);
    }
    if ($price != '') {
        $this->db->where('price', $price);
    }
    $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $data;
    }
}
```

**home.php**

```
<div class="MenuSearching" id="Searching">
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="Menu1" id="Menu1">
    <p> Lembaga</p>
        <div style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:-2px;">
            <select name="DropdownInstitution" autofocus required id="DropdownInstitution">
                <option value="no" selected="selected">---Choose one---</option>
                <option value="FlashCom">FlashCom</option>
                <option value="InterNusa">InterNusa</option>
                <option value="HexaCompare">HexaCompare</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
</div>
<div class="Menu2" id="Menu2">
    <p> Paket Kursus</p>
        <div style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:-2px;">
            <select name="DropdownCourse" autofocus required id="DropdownCourse">
                <option value="no" selected="selected">---Choose one---</option>
                <option value="web">Kursus Web Design</option>
                <option value="flash">Kursus Flash Animation</option>
                <option value="marketing">Kursus Internet Marketing</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
</div>
<div class="Menu3" id="Menu3">
    <p> Lokasi</p>
        <div style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:-3px;">
            <select name="DropdownLocation" autofocus required id="DropdownLocation">
                <option value="no" selected="selected">---Choose one---</option>
                <option value="timur">Surabaya Timur</option>
                <option value="barat">Surabaya Barat</option>
                <option value="utara">Surabaya Utara</option>
                <option value="selatan">Surabaya Selatan</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
</div>
<div class="Menu4" id="Menu4">
    <p> Harga</p>
        <div style="margin-top:-20px;margin-left:-2px;">
            <select name="DropdownPrice" autofocus required id="DropdownPrice">
                <option value="no" selected="selected">---Choose one---</option>
                <option value="harga1"> kurang dari Rp.750.000</option>
                <option value="harga2">Rp.750.000 - Rp.1.500.000</option>
                <option value="harga3">Rp.1.500.000 - Rp.2.500.000</option>
                <option value="harga4">lebih dari Rp.2.500.000</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
</div>
<div>
<input name="submitbutton" type="submit" id="submitbutton" formmethod="POST" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why you are including home.php view file in 'mymodel.php' and are you getting post data in your model ?? i suppose you are getting not as you are not passing POST data from controller to model.

Comment: I want to get other variable (example : DropdownInstitution) from home.php to mymodel.php, is it correct?

Comment: No this is not the way. The POST data should be passing from view (either by AJAX or FORM SUBMIT according to your needs) to Controller and from controller to model. Then result from MODEL needs to returned back to Controller and from controller to view.

Comment: How to pass it? I'm sorry, I'm still beginner :(

Comment: This might help you. http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/live-search-using-jquery-ajax-php-codeigniter-and-mysql.  Download jquery latest file from their official website and use it instead of what is given in mentioned url

Comment: As you are beginner , go through MVC once which help you to understand how the MCV framework works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery + Ajax to solve this non-refresh problem. 
In you home.php file, send request to your controller and after model return data to controller, data would be append on your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go through codeigniter demos of model, view and controller. 
Please check below code

**Controller.php**

```
//make a call to getinstitution function
//load our Mymodel class defined in mymodel.php
//call your view home     



    class Controller extends CI_Controller 
    {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Mymodel');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $params = array(
            'DropdownInstitution' => $this->input->post('DropdownInstitution'),
            'DropdownCourse' => $this->input->post('DropdownCourse'),
            'DropdownLocation' => $this->input->post('DropdownLocation'),
            'DropdownPrice' => $this->input->post('DropdownPrice'),            
            );

        $data['result'] = $this->mymodel->getinstitution($params);     
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
        }

    }
```

**mymodel.php**
    //No need to include('application/views/home.php');//

```
    class Mymodel extends CI_Model 
    {
    public function getinstitution($params) 
        {

        $institution = $params['DropdownInstitution'];
        $course = $params['DropdownCourse'];
        $location = $params['DropdownLocation'];
        $price = $params['DropdownPrice'];

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('courseplace');
        $this->db->where('1 = 1');
        if ($institution != '') {
            $this->db->where('institution', $institution);
        }
        if ($course != '') {
            $this->db->where('course', $course);
        }
        if ($location != '') {
            $this->db->where('location', $location);
        }
        if ($price != '') {
            $this->db->where('price', $price);
        }
        $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        return $data;
        }
    }
```

**home.php**
Please add below code to view home.php

```
    <div>
    <?php if(!empty($result)){
        foreach($result as $value){ ?>
        <?php echo $value ?>
    <?php    }   
    }else{ 
        echo 'No results';
        } ?>        
    </div><!--Result div-->
```